# NestJS/graphql - Intercept Apollo HTTP Errors

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

Does anyone know if it's possible to intercept/change Apollo's standard HTTP errors in NestJS/graphql? I can intercept standard graphql errors with filters just fine.

Best way to explain is if you start a NestJS graphql server - but with the playground disabled - and then go directly to the graphql path e.g. http://localhost:8080/graphql

Apollo throws a HttpQueryError of 'GET query missing'.

I get why it's sending the error. What I'm trying to understand is why can't I intercept these errors in NestJS like you can with all the other graphql exceptions?